# Microshift Advent rear derailleur cable pull ratio?

Tags: shifter, compatibility, shifting

What is the pull ratio of the MicroShift ADVENT rear derailleur?

I like the gearing of their 11-42 9-speed cassette and [47T derailer's capacity](https://www.microshift.com/en/product/rd-m6195l/), but not the ADVENT road shifter(s), and investigating what other (road) shifters can be used. Naturally MicroShift says "none" :)

Comment: That will cause some big jumps in the gearing with just 9 speeds. Is it for a one-by setup? Is it even compatible with that? Otherwise such a big range is not normally needed with multiple chainrings and one-by setups are better with more speeds.

Comment: @VladimirF that's not the issue at hand, AFAICT. And anyway, with 1x12 setup, I'd say most of my shifts involve jump up or down 2 gears at a time. if you've got a wide range of comfortable cadences, 1x9 should be fine.

Comment: @PaulH That surely depends on the type of riding. For road (as mentioned in the question) on needs to fine-tune the cadence and still have a large range of gears.

Comment: @VladimirF of course. but use road components doesn't mean that the riding is necessarily "road" riding. for all we know, the OP is casually commuting/running errands in a very hilly location. the point is, passing judgements on gearing gaps doesn't achieve much here.

Answer (score 2):

### **ANSWER** The numbers aren't available, but it is not an existing standard.

Their own advertising at https://www.microshift.com/en/product/sl-m8195-r/ says

> - Compatible only with ADVENT rear derailleurs
> - Not compatible with Shimano or SRAM

Also found this [quote from a microshift guy named Patrick](https://bikerumor.com/2019/02/19/microshift-advent-delivers-enduro-worthy-wide-range-9-speed-mtb-group-for-125/)  February 20, 2019 at 2:05 pm

> Proprietary cable pull actually wasn’t our first choice. microSHIFT has always played nice with cable pulls in the industry. (Check out our thumb shifters and bar end shifters) We have been Shimano compatible for a long time, but we don’t do it this time for good reasons.
>   The early prototypes were designed around traditional 9-speed cable pull. It shifted very poorly. The leverage arm on the derailleur just wasn’t long enough to move the chains up the bigger cogs. This proprietary cable pull pulls more cable to have smoother shifting and have a stronger clutch at the same time.

**Details:**

Turns out this is not a common microshift part that duplicates the specs of an existing Shimano or Sram system.  Instead they've produced a 1x system with 9 speeds stretching from 11 tooth up to 42 tooth.  Its not a full groupset, only includes a rear mech, shifter, and a cassette.

- Advent is chain agnostic - meaning it will work with any 9-speed chain.
- Rear mech has a clutch like all the other new models.
- Cassette fits a Shimano HG freehub body, so no new wheels required.

Note the rear mech looks different - the cable path is barely a right-turn compared to a 180 degree turn of other mechs.  If your gear wire came down the chainstay it would be a straight cable path into the rear mech.

[image: https://ep1.pinkbike.org/p5pb16868877/p5pb16868877.jpg from https://www.pinkbike.com/news/review-microshifts-125-advent-drivetrain.html]

Aside - I don't know how this would work if you wanted a double or triple chainset on the front.  That would not be a part of this groupset so it will be Shimano or Sram or whatever, and will use a different cable pull again.  Upshot: the left and right shifters on your bike will be different brands and probably styles.

Though I successfully run several bikes with a friction shifter for the front and whatever for the rear mech - no bother at all cos you're never changing both simultaneously.

Comment: This is not a great answer because I can't find a number for the cable pull. However it does confirm that is a new standard, which is relevant and useful.